# Communication between front end and smart contract

Tags: rust, anchor-client

Apologies if this is an obvious question, I'm very new to this! I have a webapp built in js where a user can input information, and a backend built in Rust. I want to pass that user-input information to my smart contract using Anchor client. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So typically how an Anchor application works is that you have the smart contract, a frontend for the user to interact with, and in-between that are calls to the smart contract using the @project-serum/anchor package for js/ts(which itself depends on @solana/web3.js).

In this case what you'd need to do is setup the instructions in your anchor program to include argument(s) representing the variable you'd want users to pass in. In your frontend code you'd take the information the user gives and pass that as an argument when making the RPC call to your contract. That way you get varying
logic depending on user input.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to interact with a smart contract is via transactions.  The question doesn't really give enough detail to allow further elaboration